Troubleshoot Dishwasher After Low Water Pressure Event
We recently shut off the water to the house and partially drained the system to perform some plumbing work. As the system began draining our Samsung dishwasher started beeping, flashing the "Normal" light, and running the drain. Per the owner manual this is indicates that either the leakage switch is broken, the leakage switch was activated for two seconds, or there is a problem with the main PBA. How should I troubleshoot this? It doesn't seem that the leakage switch should be impacted by the input line pressure.
Since restoring water pressure I've power cycled the unit with no effect and I've manually added water and allowed the unit to drain it also with no effect.
